# Add to hover text a Total value of all the components of a bar

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have the dataframe below:

```
dp<-structure(list(`Element Name` = c("Naphthalene", "Nitric acid (concentrated)", 
"Sulphuric acid(concentrated)", "2-hydroxybenzoic acid", "Acetic anhydride", 
"2-Naphthol", "Sodium Hydroxide", "Phenyl hydrazine hydrochloride", 
"Glucose", "Sodium acetate", "Aniline", "Zinc poweder", "2-amino-benzoic acid", 
"1.3-dihydroxybenzene", "Ethyl acetate", "hydroxy benzene", "phenyl methanol", 
"Sodium carbonate", "Potassium permanganate", "Sodium bisulfite.", 
"Hydrochloric acid (concentrated)", "Sodium nitrite", "Copper(II) sulfate", 
"Sodium chloride.", "Methyl orange", "EtOH", "Distilled water", 
"cuper ion", "ammonium hydroxide", "ammonium hydroxide", "Iron( III)", 
"Nitric Acid", "Potassium Thiocyanate", "ferric ammonium sulfate", 
"Ammonium Sulfate", "Sodium hydroxide", "sodium hypochlorite", 
"Hydrochloric acid", "Acetic acid", "Phenolphthalein", "Sodium carbonate", 
"Sodium Acetate", "Sodum hydroxide", "Acetic acid", "Hydrochloric acid", 
"Phenolphthalein", "Methyl orange", "Phosphoric acid", "Amonium hydroxide", 
"Sodium carbonate", "Iron(II) sulfate", "Potassium permanganate", 
"Sulfuric Acid", "Barium Chloride.monoHydrate", "Distilled water", 
"nickel Sulphate", "Dimethyl glyoxime (DMG)", "Calsium chloride", 
"Calsium Carbonate", "Ammonium oxalate", "potassium chromate", 
"Lead (II) Nitrate", "   Ammonium thiocyanate10%", "Copper(II) sulfate", 
"Nitric acid", "    Iron (II)", "Ammonium Nitrate", "Chloroform", 
"Iodine solution", "sodiumThiosulphates", "Copper(II) sulfate", 
"Amonia solution", "murexide", "Lead (II) Nitrate", "ammonium chloride", 
"sodium diethyl dicabamate", "Eriochrome Black T", "nikel sulphate", 
"Ethanol", "Dimethyl glyoxime (DMG)", "Methyl orange", "Sodium bicarbonate", 
"Calcium chloride", "Tartaric acid", "Iron(II) sulfate", "Hydrogen peroxide", 
"Sodium Hydroxide", "Sulfuric Acid", "Citric acid", "Benzoic acid", 
"Methanol", "Ethanol", "Iron(III) Chloride", "Phenol", "Phthalic acid", 
"Salicylic acid", "Ammonium oxalate", "Hydrochloric acid (concentrated)", 
"Ammonium tartarate", "Ammonium citrate"), DemandCourse = c(240, 
375, 1050, 300, 1614, 225, 75, 414, 414, 225, 450, 111, 675, 
105, 120, 375, 75, 75, 375, 150, 750, 264, 975, 900, 20, 250, 
30, 25, 2500, 2500, 15, 500, 730, 25, 170, 240, 75, 750, 255, 
10, 160, 50, 144, 54, 630, 15, 18, 132, 900, 48, 138, 36, 300, 
2250, 45, 1500, 90, 999, 15, 750, 120, 996, 300, 480, 234, 30, 
30, 20, 80, 64, 64, 500, 24, 24, 212, 24, 20, 200, 20, 32, 20, 
100, 100, 60, 100, 100, 200, 200, 60, 60, 240, 240, 100, 200, 
60, 60, 60, 200, 60, 60), AmountsAv = c(NA, 1000, 3000, 4000, 
1000, 750, 750, 2000, 5000, 150, 24000, 450, 3000, 1400, 400, 
400, 250, 250, 1000, 1000, 7500, 6400, 900, NA, 250, 1500, 20000, 
50, 300, 4000, 200, NA, 3000, 500, 1200, NA, 1000, NA, 6000, 
900, 250, NA, 200, 6000, NA, 900, 250, 200, NA, 250, 150, 1000, 
15000, 3000, 20000, 1500, 600, 7500, 20, 500, 300, 1600, 400, 
900, 300, NA, 10, 12000, 200, 20, 900, 400, 180, 1600, 180, 20, 
750, 200, 5000, 600, 250, 3000, 1800, 1500, 150, 250, 750, 15000, 
150, 250, 200, 5000, 400, 150, 300, 1500, 500, 7500, 300, 400
)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), na.action = structure(293:294, .Names = c("293", "294"), class = "omit"))
```

amd I create the grouped bar chart but as you can see in the screenshot while the height of the bars is correct the value in the hover text is different.I guess this happens because there are more than one elements with same name for some cases.What I need is to add a `Total` value in the hover text.
[image]

```
fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`, data = dp) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse`, 
           name = "Demand", 
           textposition = "none",          # <--- added here
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>", 
                                  "Demand: %{y}<br>"
                                  )) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~AmountsAv,
           name = "Amount Available", 
           textposition = "none",          # <--- added here
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>",  
                                  "Available Amount: %{y}<br>"
                                  )) %>% 
  layout(barmode = "group",              # <--- dropped showLegend (doesn't go here)
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name", tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title = "Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to aggregate your data before plotting:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

dp <- dp %>% 
  group_by(`Element Name`) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm = TRUE))

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~`Element Name`, data = dp) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~`DemandCourse`, 
           name = "Demand", 
           textposition = "none",          # <--- added here
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>", 
                                  "Demand: %{y}<br>"
           )) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~AmountsAv,
           name = "Amount Available", 
           textposition = "none",          # <--- added here
           hovertemplate = paste0("Chemical Name: %{x}<br>",  
                                  "Available Amount: %{y}<br>"
           )) %>% 
  layout(barmode = "group",              # <--- dropped showLegend (doesn't go here)
         xaxis = list(title = "Element Name", tickangle=45),
         yaxis = list(title = "Amount Available"),
         title = "Amount and Demand per Element")
fig
```

[image]